# How to get Button Id inside "data-content" atrribute of html tag in code-behind file to fire evnt

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In vb .aspx  Inside data-content attribute i have my TextBox and Button Control . But there id not visible in code-behind .i need to fire evnt on button. how to fire event on button??

```html
<a
   data-content='<asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />'
data-html='true' data-toggle='popover' href='#' title='UserName'><%#Eval("Name")%></a>
```

I need to fire event in code-behind... Any Suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me correctly, the `ID` of an asp control, like `asp:Button` is essentially the name of the control variable in code-behind. You need to reach it from something like the aspx.vb file

The attribute of `OnClick="Event_Name"` could be helpful in [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you need a client-side click, then you might want to work with the `ClientID` data member or the `onclick` html attribute of the generated tag.